# Using Python to replace MATLAB: how to import data?

Tags: python, excel, matlab, numpy

I want to use some Python libraries to replace MATLAB. How could I import Excel data in Python (for example using [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy)) to use them?

I don't know if Python is a credible alternative to MATLAB, but I want to try it. Is there a a tutorial?

Comment: One way to interpret the original question is: how can I read a (proprietary) Excel (.xls, .xlsx) file into Python. An answer to this could be useful, but I don't have one. So, the general flow here is to export in another format from Excel, namely, CSV.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on what kind of computations you are doing with [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) (and on which toolboxes you are using), Python could be a good alternative to MATLAB.

Python + [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) + [SciPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy) + [Matplotlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib) are the right combination to start.

For the data, you can, for example, save your data directly in text file (assuming that you are not directly concerned by floating-point precision issues) and read it in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29).

If your data are [Excel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) data, where each value is separated by a ";", you can for example read the file line by line, and use the split() method (with ";" as argument) to get each value.

For MATLAB up to version 7.1, it is possible to directly load .mat files from Python with the [scipy.io.matlab.mio](http://www.scipy.org/doc/api_docs/SciPy.io.mio.html) module.

Answer (score 3):

There are probably hundreds of ways you could import text data into Python.

But since you want to replace [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), you're going be using [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) and probably [SciPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy).

Keep things simple: use NumPy's standard text-loading:

```
import numpy
imported_array = numpy.loadtxt('file.txt',delimiter='\t')  # Assuming tab-delimiter
print imported_array.shape
```

Answer (score 3):

Pandas is a Python data analysis library that can import/export from Excel pretty easily. Here's how to do it:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#excel

Crash course:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('foo.xlsx', 'Sheet1', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])
```

Answer (score 2):

There's [Matplotlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib) for plots and the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) for reading [Excel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) data (assuming you can dump to [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)).

Here's [a tutorial](http://vnoel.wordpress.com/2008/05/03/bye-matlab-hello-python-thanks-sage/) about replacing [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) with Python.

Comment: SAGE (mentionend in the tutorial, see http://sagemath.org/) is a pretty cool stack based on Python.

Comment: Thanx a lot. I'm going to try SAGE.

Answer (score 2):

If you come from the [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) world, [Pylab](http://www.scipy.org/PyLab) will ease your transition. Once you have converted your data to ASCII, `pylab.load()` will do the rest:

```
pylab.load(fname, comments='#', delimiter=None, converters=None, 
           skiprows=0, usecols=None, unpack=False, 
           dtype=<type 'numpy.float64'>)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a look at [mlabwrap](http://mlabwrap.sourceforge.net/) as a step to easing some [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) developers into using Python more.

But I have been unable to cleanly build it, and I don't run production installs here, so I'm dead in the water.

Answer (score 1):

If you saved you data in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) format, use:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat

datafile = "yourfile.mat"
data = loadmat(datafile, matlab_compatible=True)
var1 = data['nameOfYourVariable'].squeeze()
var2 = data['nameOfYourOtherVariable'].squeeze()
```

Answer (score 1):

> "I don't know if Python is a credible alternative to MATLAB"

For me (experimental physics) Python is not only a full replacement for [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) (when including [SciPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy) and [Matplotlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib) as mentioned above), but it is useful for many things other than data crunching and visualisation (such are general programming needs).

> "I'm going to try SAGE."

It is worth noting that there are a couple of servers running [Sage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sage_%28mathematics_software%29) which offer the notebook environmet (check [Try Sage online](http://www.sagenb.org/) in http://www.sagemath.org/). This is pretty neat given the fact that all you need it is an Internet browser and access (no installation required).

As for the question as interpreted by Kevin Buchs (in another answer), reading proprietary Excel to Python can be done in several methods, some are platform (OS) dependent:

1. A nice resource (platform independent) - http://www.python-excel.org/
2. An example using [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) which I once found useful (this is what I used when I needed it): http://code.activestate.com/recipes/483742/ for an example based on xlrd (platform independent)
3. [pyexcelerator](http://pyexcelerator.sourceforge.net/) is another option.

I hope this helps. If not, I can try to arrange some example code myself (though the ones I have are over six years old...). I personally prefer, as was proposed in the other answers, to use the CSV or ASCII format.